# Disable Class onclick until another button is clicked

Tags: jquery, button

I have one div with 4 spans in it:

```
<div id="text">
<span class="text_1" id="text1">text1 1</span>
<span class="text_2" id="text2">text2 2</span>
<span class="text_3" id="text3">text3 3</span>
<span class="text_4" id="text4">text4 4</span>
</div>
```

I have two buttons, buton1 that allows the class underline

```
.underline
 { border-bottom:1px solid #000; }
```

to be added to each span when i click each span (so if I click text1, then the other texts shouldn't have an underline), and another button2 that should take off the underline until button1 is clicked again.

What I have is:

```
$('#button1').click(function () {

    $(".text_1").click(function () {
     $(".text_2").removeClass("underline");
     $(".text_3").removeClass("underline");
     $(".text_4").removeClass("underline");
     $('.text_1').addClass("underline");
});

     $(".text_2").click(function () {

     $(".text_1").removeClass("underline");
     $(".text_3").removeClass("underline");
     $(".text_4").removeClass("underline");
     $('.text_2').addClass("underline");
});
$(".text_3").click(function () {

     $(".text_2").removeClass("underline");
     $(".text_1").removeClass("underline");
     $(".text_4").removeClass("underline");
     $('.text_3').addClass("underline");
});

     $(".text_4").click(function () {

     $(".text_2").removeClass("underline");
     $(".text_1").removeClass("underline");
     $(".text_3").removeClass("underline");
     $('.text_4').addClass("underline");
}); 
});
```

meaning all of the above would happen iff button1 is clicked.

so button2, I want it to remove all underline from everything, but I don't want to have to do all of the above over again because eventually I'm going to have like 100 span tags!

What I thought was correct would be something like

```
$('#button2').click(function () {

        $('#text').removeClass("underline") });   });
```

but that doesn't work. (#text being the div id)

I then tried

```
$('#button2').click(function () {
     $(".text_2").removeClass("underline");
     $(".text_1").removeClass("underline");
     $(".text_3").removeClass("underline");
     $('.text_4').removeClass("underline");
```

I want it so that after you click button2, I cannot make the span text underline until I click button1. So the one directly above removes the underline class, but I can still click each span element and make it underline which I don't want!

Could someone help me with this? I'm sort of new at this, so It'd be great if you could help me clean up button1's functions too!!
Thank you!

Comment: Any reason why you're using `border-bottom:1px solid #000` instead of `text-decoration:underline`?

Comment: You should mark the correct answer whenever it is done, so that next time you will get quick answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. Try the [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hG4hM/1/)

```
var allowClick = true;

$('#text span').click(function () {
  if (allowClick == true) {
    $('#text span').removeClass("underline");
    $(this).addClass("underline");
  }
});

$('#button1').click(function () {
  allowClick = true;
});

$('#button2').click(function () {
  $('#text span').removeClass("underline");
  allowClick = false;
});
```

**Update:**

There is another solution also in which you can unbind the click event on span. But using a variable will be simple and faster. Consider unbinding if you can not create a global variable.

Comment: Hmmm it's still doing the same thing, where it will remove the underline class but the span elements are still underlining when I click them even though I didn't click on the button1! though thank you this does give me a good shorthand to do things similiar to this function haha..forgot about adding the span part!

Answer (score 1):

How about this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4zNT/)

```
$("span").on("click", function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('underline').end().addClass("underline");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#button2').click(function () {
    $('.underline').removeClass('underline');
    $('#text span').unbind('click');
});
```

After this, just turn on the `underline` for what you need.

Also, you can make the `button1` click like this:

```
$('#button1').click(function () {
    $("#text span").click(function () {
        $('.underline').removeClass('underline');
        $(this).addClass('underline');
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah! It almost works... it does the same thing that I tried in my attempted solution, it removes the underline class but the span elements still underline when I click them even if I don't click button1 =\

Comment: Updated, now the event will not be handled by the `span`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){ 
  $("#text").removeClass("disable-underline");
});
$("#button2").click(function(){ 
  $("#text").addClass("disable-underline");
});

$("#text span").on("click", function(){
  $("#text span").removeClass("underline");
  $(this).addClass("underline");
});
```

CSS:

```
.underline { border-bottom:1px solid #000; }
.disable-underline .underline { border-bottom: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand you totally correct.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kYg8k/

Firstly, lets handle all span clicks in one line. This adding class to clicked span and removing from its siblings.

```
$("#text SPAN").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("underline").siblings().removeClass("underline");
});
```

Next button2 to remove underline class from any underlined span

```
$(".bt2").click(function(){
    $("#text SPAN").removeClass("underline");
});
```

Finally button1 that enables underlining by adding some flag class to #text

```
$(".bt1").click(function(){
  $("#text").toggleClass("underlinable");
});
```

and lets use this flag on event

```
$("#text SPAN").click(function(){
  if ($(this).closest("#text").hasClass("underlinable")) {
    $(this).addClass("underline").siblings().removeClass("underline");
  }
});
```

(In demo I have little advanced code with flag indication.)